# Не мог переместить эмулятор Android Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, android-emulator

Так как у меня закончилось свободное место на диске, я хотел переместить эмулятор Android на другой диск. Но после перемещения, появляется ошибка, что эмулятор невозможно найти в том расположении, в котором он был раньше.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]